# Delete a relationship?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-relationship, navigation-properties

What is the opposite of:

```
Dim ad As New Address
Person.AddressReference.Attach(ad)
```

I mean how do I delete the Person.Address? (both with deleting and without - meaning only delete the relation)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't do VB, so forgive me if my syntax isn't quite right.

To "attach":

```
Person.Address = ad
```

To "detach"

```
Person.Address = Nothing
```

If you want to delete, then do:

```
Context.DeleteObject(ad)
```

Comment: Then why on earth are you using `Attach`?!? That makes almost no sense. What are you trying to accomplish by not just assigning the relationship directly: `Person.Address = ad`? I'll update my answer, but I feel like there must be something going on here which you haven't mentioned.

Comment: Does the `DeleteObject` take care of the detaching too (i.e. setting null in the forgein's relation ID property)?

Comment: Not necessarily. Depends on whether it's a cascade. See this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/08/19/tip-33-how-cascade-delete-really-works-in-ef.aspx